# CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript throws System.Exception

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, webview2

CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript throws System.Exception: 'The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.'
Version
SDK: 1.0.1245.22 latest stable - (and Microsoft.UI.Xaml 2.8.0-prerelease.210927001)
Runtime:
Framework: UWP
OS: Windows 11, build 22000

Reproduce Steps

1. Create an UWP project
2. Add necessary nuget packages (Microsoft.Web.Webview2 latest stable release and Microsoft.UI.Xaml 2.8.0-prerelease)
3. Add WebView2 component to MainPage.xaml
4. Create HostObject class with necessary tags
5. Add code for navigation starting or navigation completed method in WebView2 (MainPage.xaml.cs)
6. Ensure CoreWebView2 is not null by calling myWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(); inside method
7. Try use myWebView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("HostObject", hostObject); inside method
   (Also tried to make a new project uwp (as Windows Runtime Component) and create the HostObject class there but still same exception. In addition tried to change tags on HostObject class but still same issue)

Example of HostObject class:

```
[AllowForWeb]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class JsCallbacksUwp
{
    public JsCallbacksUwp()
    {

    }
}
```

Example code for Navigation Completed that throws the exception:

```
private async void WebView2_NavigationCompleted(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    await sender.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();    
    var browserHostObject = new JSCallbacksUwp();    
    sender.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("HostObject", browserHostObject);
}
```

[image: Exception Thrown Image]

Comment: AllowForWeb attribute available for the old edge engine webview, but for webview2, there is not document tell if it is still available , please go ahead report this problem in winui [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues)

Comment: Like i said in the question "In addition tried to change tags on HostObject class but still same issue". I tried a lot of different combination of tags and one of them was to remove "AllowForWeb" tag but unfortunately still same result...

Comment: Well, currently the better way is report it in winui issue box, and I will disscuss team if there is a workaroud for this .

Comment: I reported the issue into the [WebView2 Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2529) but will try winui too... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from github's community at [WebView2 Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2529).

Firstly i followed the guide that [Syul968](https://github.com/Syul968) showed me there which was:

> The WinRT CoreWebView2 class (the one used by WinUI) tries to automatically create a "wrapper" when this is the case, but it needs a DispatchAdapter instance to be set through CoreWebView2Settings.HostObjectDispatchAdapter.
> We have also been working on this feature lately. Our latest pre-release package ([1.0.1248-prerelease](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/1.0.1248-prerelease)) includes a tool, wv2winrt, to help project new and existing WinRT components: [Call native-side WinRT code from web-side code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/winrt-from-js?tabs=csharp)

Secondly i followed the steps from [david-risney](https://github.com/david-risney) answer:

> Our current documentation only shows you how to do it for OS provided WinRT APIs and not for your own WinRT APIs. We need to fix this. Until then I would recommend following the existing directions from Call native-side WinRT code from web-side code, and then additionally doing the following:
>
> 1. Add a third project to your VS solution that implements your winrt class.
> 2. Have the WinRTAdapter project 'Add a reference' to your new third project containing your winrt class.
> 3. Update the WinRTAdapter project's Include filter to also include your new class.
> 4. Add an additional line to InitializeWebView2Async to add your winrt class's namespace
>    WebView2.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("MyCustomNamespace",
>    dispatchAdapter.WrapNamedObject("MyCustomNamespace",
>    dispatchAdapter));
> 5. And optionally add your namespace sync proxy as a global object in script window.MyCustomNamespace =
>    chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync.MyCustomNamespace; You should then be able to use your type via script.

Lastly you can check my changes to my [example](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2529#issuecomment-1164508491).

Comment: Please see the following answer . 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300119/1146253

Think about the deletion of your answer.

Comment: According to the link that you send me it says: "Else if it might be helpful to others, write a self-answer if there's no good answer yet. If there is one, accept the best and be done". So because i found the answer useful if someone else has the same problem as me, i don't think i should delete it. Thank you though for your consideration.